Simulating button click on existing page using Chrome extension in v3
I am building a Chrome extension that is injecting new text and links on the webpage.  I need one of these links, when clicked, to essentially simulate multiple clicks (and other tasks) of pre-existing buttons on the webpage.  For example, on the Amazon checkout page, can a user click on an "Update-Shipping Address" link I injected and it essentially simulates the necessary tasks of clicking "Change", adding a new address on the user's Amazon account?
I have tried reviewing but it seems that since v3 of manifest.json this functionality might be questionable?  Even so, I'd like to make this happen.

Use a content script. There's nothing in ManifestV3 that prevents doing that.

Tried it, but didn't work at all... it scrolls up to the address section and then just dies.  Offering $50 reward for any one who can make it happen.
